# Can Javascript press the Enter key for me?

Tags: javascript, button, keyboard, bots

There's a site that I want to continue to hit enter on while I'm away. Is it possible to do something like

```
setInterval(function(){
    //have javascript press the button with a certain id
},100);
```

I was thinking of just putting that in the smart search bar so it would run the code.

Comment: Unless you find a way to inject the code using XSS (cross site scripting). I don't think you will be able to do it.

Comment: @Jacques: It's trivial in this case: You just open the web console and type. That code is run in the same environment as the page you're viewing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you are right i never thought of that. In that case i guess its possible

Answer (score 13):

Well pressing enter is triggering an `event`. You would have to figure out which event listener they are listening to. I'll use `keyup` in the following example:

Assume `el` is the variable for the element you want enter to be pressed on. I'm not sure how you going to get that element but I'm sure you know.

```
var evt = new CustomEvent('keyup');
evt.which = 13;
evt.keyCode = 13;
el.dispatchEvent(evt); //This would trigger the event listener.
```

There's no way to actually simulate a hardware action. It just triggers the event listener.

For example calling `el.click()` is only calling the callback of the event listener, not actually pressing the key.

So you know how when you add an event listener to an element the first argument is the `event` object.

```
el.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   //Do Something
});
```

Above `event` is equal to `evt` when calling `dispatchEvent` on `el`

If the programmer used:

```
el.onkeyup = function(event) {
  //do whatever.
}
```

It's surprisingly easy.

Just call `el.onkeyup(evt);`

Because `onkeyup` is a function.

Why did I use `CustomEvent` instead of `KeyboardEvent` because `new KeyboardEvent('keyup')` return's an object with the properties `which` and `keyCode` that can't be rewritten without the use of `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties`