# Why cant I press enter programatically?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to *fire off* a search programatically having populated the input.

Can't find a clear Javascript example of that though. Jquery not really an option as i want to keep this a lightweight Chrome Extension.

Emitting the 'Enter' event just seems to return a true with no search actually beginning.

HTML

```
<form id="form">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search Foo" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
const input = document.querySelector(`input[placeholder="Search Foo"]`);
// ^^ targets element successfully

input.value = "this is my search term";
// ^^ adds value to input fine.

input.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
// ^^ appears to focus correctly

input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'keyCode': 13}));
// ^^ returns 'true' in console but nothing happens.

const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.submit();
// ^^ triggers a full page refresh, not an 'enter' / submit action.
```

I have tried a few variations around this (deprecated KeyEvents syntax mostly).

Why can't I actually fire off 'Enter' / submit on the input/form?

Comment: Do you have a function that searches the data on clicking enter?

Comment: I think you should use keypress or keyup event instated of enter

Comment: keyCode 38 is up arrow. "Enter" is keyCode 13.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren thanks, updated that but still not firing off.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya i'm afraid not, i have to go this route, directly hitting the input. It's to automate some web activitiy within a Chrome Extension.

Comment: @Aid19801 Are you sure the query selector returns the correct input? and are you sure that pressing "enter" would do anything special? and that you aren't looking for "submitting" a form?

Comment: @vallentin turns out it *IS* inside a form, just way higher up, apologies. So i've now written a function that populates the value of the input in 300ms increments. Then i target the form and fire `form.submit()` *BUT* this refreshes the entire page rather than starts a search. Any ideas? I'm searching for solutions now.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing even is triggering an `event` you need to find what event the code is listening to the below would work for `keyup` event

```
var evt = new CustomEvent('keyup');
evt.which = 13;
evt.keyCode = 13;
input.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Have a look at this answer it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720843/13335890

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the input in a form element and then call `form.submit()` on the form element.

Comment: Thanks for this but form.submit() seems to trigger full page refresh. Just having a look around now for why that is and how to overcome it. Unless you know why/how?

Comment: Add a submit event listener to the form and call `event.preventDefault()` in the listener function and then fire off the search programmatically in that same function after calling `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: The `event` in this case is the parameter you pass in the listener function.